# SimpleXmlElement count

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to count the amount of children in a `SimpleXmlElement`. I've searched on StackOverflow but I can't seem to find anything;

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml as $key => $field) {
    if (count($field) == 0){
        $field[0][0] = 'test';
    }
}
```

Some of my `XmlElement` are empty. Yet count gives 0 on all the elements. The only way I've found to do what I want is this:

```
if ($field[0][0] == '')
```

I've tried using $field->count() as specified on http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php, but no matter what is in $field, it always returns 0.

Isn't there a better way to do this?

Here is the format of the xml through print_r:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [firstName] => Test
    [lastName] => Test2
    [middleName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($xml);`so we can see the format?

Comment: Yea, of course, I just added the print_r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the count() function like this:

```
$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$elem->count();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php for reference.

Comment: I've tried this before. But the issue is that no matter what is in $field, $field->count() returns 0. $field = {SimpleXMLElement}[1] but $field->count() = 0

Comment: Don't apply it to $field, it has to be applied to $xml in your case as it already counts the children. Ergo you don't have to iterate through the object to get the number of child nodes.